# Can a void pointer point to a lambda function?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, void-pointers

Assigning a function pointer to a `void` pointer,

```
double f_dummy(double x) { return x; }
...
    void *pv = f_dummy;  //compilation error
```

is illegal as explained in this [FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#cant-cvt-fnptr-to-voidptr). The answer, however, closes with the statement :

*Please do not email me if the above seems to work on your particular version of your particular compiler on your particular operating system. I don’t care. It’s illegal, period.*

**Edit** : As a warning to others, I did encounter this "*seems to work*" behavior, through a case of inheritance involving class templates. No compiler warning, no unexpected run-time behavior.

This tickles my OCD bone and makes me wonder if what I've been doing, e.g.,

```
...
    auto l_func = [](double x){ return f_dummy(x); };
    void *pv = &l_func;
    auto pl = static_cast<decltype(&l_func)>(pv);
    cout << (*pl)(5.) << endl;
```

which compiles and runs cleanly (`g++ -std=c++11 -Wall`), is truly legal. Is it?

Comment: `l_func` is not a function. It's an object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's legal, because:

- pointers to objects may be cast to `void*` and back again;
- `l_func` is an object (a functor, with unspecified class type) — that's how lambdas are implemented, by standard mandate.

The FAQ text you cite is unrelated, as it refers to pointers to *functions*. `_yourUnspecifiedLambdaType::operator()` is the equivalent* function, but you're not doing anything with that here.

<sub><sup>*</sup> Well, it's not even equivalent, because it's a *member* function!</sub>

Comment: Great (and succinct) answer, plus one! Great hat also;)) Although all this type erasure non-sense should disappear ASAP. I'm not trying to convert C++ into Haskell, but let's be serious, one can do perfectly reasonable programming without `void*`. Overloading operator `new` shouldn't really happen except when it must do (like 0.01% of the time).

Comment: @vsoftco: Agreed on all (all!) counts ;p

Comment: I'm still trying to chillaxx although my tooth hurts like a m...f..r. Dentist on Fri, any advice before? Alcohol DOES NOT WORK unfortunately :(

Comment: @vsoftco: You could try spending some time programming in Turbo-C++. You're likely to find it so painful that you forget all about your dodgy tooth.